# Serlializing a property XML content 'as is'

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization

There is something I don't now how to
handle. I amb XML serializing an object and need to serialize a property
content "as is", as an XML structure. By default, the system is
'encoding (&amp;, &lt;...) the entitites, but I need the xml tree.

(sample)

Dim tmp as myClass

tmp.Value = "this is
<b>Bold</b>"

'The serialized string is

......<value>this is
&lt;b&gt;Bold&lt;/b&gt;</value>

'and what I need is

<value>this is
<b>Bold</b></value>

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the elements data/contents in a [`<![CDATA[]]>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) block to maintain it literally:

> In an XML document or external parsed entity, a CDATA section is a
>   section of element content that is marked for the parser to interpret
>   as only character data, not markup.

Comment: I forgot to say that the schema does not allow CDATA (i know that is the smart solution). The only way is to create the XML structure serlialyzing.